# How to set new properties or methods on a Java array?

Tags: java

Is it possible to set new properties or methods on a Java array? Alternatively, how would I be able to create a new type of array in which I would be able to define non-default properties or methods?

Comment: Please include more details and clarify the issue you are having.

Comment: I am not sure how I can be more clear. I want to be able to set non-default properties or methods on an array, e.g. myArray.myProperty = myValue. myArray should have all of the properties and methods of a default Java array plus any property or method I feel like including.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t.

Arrays are special. For example, the Java language supports c-like syntax for accessing elements:

```
myArray[n]
```

and the class of the array objects themselves is a not regular java class:

```
Object obj = new String[0];  
System.out.println(obj.getClass() == String[].class); // true
```

which shows that arrays go beyond being just another class.

Arrays are a fundamental part of the language. Asking if you can extend them is a bit like asking if you can extend the `int` type.

The [Array class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html), which is a utility class to dynamically create and access arrays, is `final` and thus cannot be extended, but it wouldn't help even if you could because arrays are not instances of  that class.

Comment: Okay, does that mean that we can also not create our own types of array-like objects?

Comment: @User8675309 the `ArrayList` class is “array like” and can be extended. You can’t use array style syntax - you must use the `get()` method, but is essentially a thin wrapper over an array. It’s also much more convenient to work with than a raw array.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Virtual Machine encapsulates the array class. The array class is not part of the platform API; user code cannot extend it.

If you want to extend arrays, consider using object composition. That is, make a class that has an array. This class's methods can modify the array as needed.